# Multiple Terminals displayed as a grid in one window

Tags: mac, terminal

Is there a way to have one window display more than one terminal at once? (Not in the typical tabbed configuration, more like a grid of arbitrary number of terminal screens)

Ideally I'd like to have a 3 column by 2 row window with 6 terminal instances in the one window.

An application with this as a feature is preferable.

Comment: check out this question as well: http://superuser.com/questions/55459/how-to-get-vertical-split-of-terminal-in-mac-to-execute-different-actions/55464#55464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Terminator](http://www.debuntu.org/terminator-a-multi-view-terminal) which comes as a Debian package.
Maybe you can get it working on your Mac (use the [source](https://launchpad.net/terminator/+download)).

Answer (score 2):

[GNU Screen for Mac](http://screen.darwinports.com/) can do this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a tiling window manager with multiple terminals to arrange them quickly and easily in any such configuration. Use a workspaces feature that is in almost all linux window managers to switch between that layout and other window layouts (like regular maximized apps). I prefer xmonad. Another nice feature of a tiling window manager is that you can remove the titlebars from those 6 windows to remove wasted space.