# Terminal emulator with split panes for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, terminator

I'm looking for a terminal emulator on Mac OSX with a specific feature:

**to be able to split the console window into multiple panes.**

It's a great feature of Terminator for gnome, I think this image describes it best:

[image]

Notice that every pane is a different prompt with different applications running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want another Terminal Emulator (instead of Terminal.app), use iTerm2, as Daniel Beck suggests. 
If you want to split the Terminal.app window into multiple ones, use either "[screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)" (already part of the standard Mac OS X installation), install "[tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)" or [split windows in emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html%5Fnode/emacs/Split-Window.html).

P.S. Very similar questions have already been asked (and answered), e.g. here: [How to get vertical split of terminal in Mac to execute different actions?](https://superuser.com/questions/55459/how-to-get-vertical-split-of-terminal-in-mac-to-execute-different-actions)

Comment: iTerm2 added terminal splitting in a recent release.

Answer (score 3):

[iTerm 2](http://sites.google.com/site/iterm2home/) supports this. Compare login times in the screenshot.

<sup>Don't know what's wrong with my PS1 though, I use Terminal usually.</sup>
[image]

Comment: I've found that iTerm2 doesn't render PS1 correctly if it's anything non-trivial. That's actually the only reason I'm still using Terminal.app