# Terminal emulator with split panes for Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: windows, command-line, 64-bit, terminal-emulator, terminator

I'm looking for a terminal emulator on Windows 7 (64 bit) with a specific feature:

to be able to split the command prompt window into multiple panes.

It's a great feature of Terminator for gnome, I think this image describes it best:

[image]

Notice that every pane is a different shell with different applications

**NOTE**: this question is similar to another one I asked: [Terminal emulator with split panes for Mac OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/242271/terminal-emulator-with-split-panes-for-mac-osx),
 but this time I'm asking for a solution in a Windows environment

**EDIT**: for reference, here's more about Terminator: http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html

Comment: In case you are on Windows 10, you can have Terminator with WSL:
https://blog.ropnop.com/configuring-a-pretty-and-usable-terminal-emulator-for-wsl/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just saw this mentioned in another answer, and remembered that you were looking for something like this.

[**PowerCmd**](http://www.powercmd.com/)

[image: PowerCmd]

I just use Console2 with TCC/LE and PowerShell, myself.

Comment: PowerCmd needs administrator privilege to run, so on Vista/Win7 it will trigger a UAC prompt each time you run it, quite annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't handle terminal colors like cmd.

Comment: Is this capable of remote CLI using SSH?

Answer (score 67):

I'm the author of another terminal - [ConEmu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560) (open source). This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/473846/139371) describes how to run 2x2 grid on startup. Actually, any configuration of splits (up to 30 panes) can be configured. Also, each split can be run as different users or elevated (Vista and higher). Any console and simple GUI (like mintty/putty) applications may be run in ConEmu tabs.

[image: ConEmu split-screen feature]

How to create a split?

1) From create new console dialog. Just press `[+]` button on toolbar or <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>. Choose your app, working dir, user name and split configuration.

[image: New console dialog in ConEmu]

2) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> split active shell vertically or horizontally. Press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> to see full hotkeys list.

3) Save your configured split-panes into new named task to get it on fast access next time. Open Settings dialog <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and go to "Tasks" page. Add new task (`+` button) and press `Active tabs`. Your task will be filled with your current split configuration. Don't forget to `Save settings`. For example

```
>cmd -new_console:n
powershell -new_console:s1TVn
sh --login -i -new_console:s1THn
putty -load mysrv -new_console:s2THn
```

---

### Another free alternatives

[ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) (fork of Console2)
[image: ConsoleZ]

[Alternative Windows Console](https://sourceforge.net/projects/windowsconsole/)
[image: AWC]

Comment: I've used ConEmu for at least a year and can vouch for it. I didn't know it could do split panes and found this post while looking for Terminator for Windows (I also use Terminator on Linux). Big thanks to you Maximus both for ConEmu and for providing this info!

Comment: Upvote for stating that you arere the author and providing links to alternative software. Other users could learn from your answer.

Comment: Im a little confused by your 'how to split' explanation. In iTerm2 I can just do Command-D or Command-Shift-D to split a tab. End of story. Can/Do I have this capability with your app? Thanks. I dont want to 'setup' every time I want to split. I would like to just press some hotkeys and get a split. Can your app do that?

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond Read answer again. Will there. Exactly "2".

Comment: Is it possible to send commands to multiple panes, like in iTerm2 & terminator, with conemu on Windows? example: http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/35-send-command-to-all-iterm-2-panes

Comment: Yes. Apps+G by default

Comment: Cmder is ConEmu compliant (http://rakhesh.com/windows/whee-cmder-can-do-split-panes/)

Comment: Thank you - I've been using Console2 for years, but its quirks and limitations are finally getting to me. I'll try ConEmu. :)

Comment: weird, I saved the layout, but when I close the program and start it again, the program opens a new cmd as usual, then I start my previously saved task, but the layout is stumbling, not looks like previously saved.

Comment: @truongnm Version from year 2015? Update it!

Comment: Vouching for ConEmu right here! Just downloaded and set it up. Took about 10 seconds to learn and using the answer linked above, startup with my tabs was painless :D It even supported Git Bash right out of the box! In case anyone has trouble finding it, once you set up your Task in settings, click the Startup pane and use your "Specified named task" to run it.

Answer (score 20):

The best Terminator parallel for Windows is:

### [**Cmder**](http://cmder.app/)

---

- You can use **split panes** in *Cmder*
- It supports **tabs**

[image]

---

- It also allows for running a program (like Sublime Text) in a pane

[image]

**[Note:** The larger *msysgit* version of Cmder comes places Git and all Unix commands in your PATH **]**

Comment: It is [ConEmu](http://superuser.com/a/667594/139371)+git+clink actually.

Comment: It doesn't work with WSL

Answer (score 8):

I've looked around and have settled on mobaxterm. It is a simple windows install but pulls in the features of terminator and winSCP. I'm pretty happy with it but would be pleasantly surprised to find a better windows based terminal to keep me connected.

http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/

Comment: +1 for MobaXterm: the "split view" mode allows me to have up to 4 consoles at different sizes with easy navigation through them using Ctrl+Tab!

Comment: Although it has a bunch of features I don't quite like how MobaXTerm handles split view. First, there is only the option of 2 or 4 split. I want to be able customize this more and arrange the subwindows the way I want. Also I find that the borders of the windows in split mode are way too large and take away space. It's cool though that you only cycle through the windows selected for split view, but the fact thats its a separate "mode" kills it for me.

Answer (score 6):

The Terminator from http://software.jessies.org/terminator/ requires installation of Cygwin, which is a bit more work than using ComEmu

Comment: This should have been a comment to the Mark Allen's reply. After gaining 50 points of reputation you will be able comment on posts of others.

Answer (score 0):

According to the home page for Terminator, it's cross platform and runs on Windows. So... Terminator?

http://software.jessies.org/terminator/

Comment: No. That's a software with the same name and without the feature I described. The Terminator I'm referring to is this: http://www.tenshu.net/terminator/

Comment: Ah, sorry then!

Comment: I didn't know about this one. Thanks!

Comment: The current URL of the project is https://code.google.com/p/jessies/.

Answer (score 0):

[MRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org/). It will allows you to connect to many ports (SSH 1/2, RDP, VNC, etc) in one window. Support splitted & tabbed window. One for all application for remoting. Give it a try.

Comment: MRemoteNG is a remote connection manager - not a console/terminal emulator.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Ctrl + Shift + O  or Ctrl + Shift + E for vertical/horizonal  spliting

[image]

Comment: (1) Since you don’t even say what program you’re talking about, this does not answer the question.    (2) I can see from your image that you’re talking about ConEmu.   Based on that, I can see that your post is a subset of [Maximus’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/268042/354511#667594).