# Conemu: How do I make several console windows in one tab from task file?

Tags: tasks, conemu

How to make several console windows in one tab from task file?
I want to make a grid 2×2 of consoles in one tab.
I can do it by hand when create new consoles and select "To right" or "To bottom" options.
But I want it to be created automatically on start up. Option "autosave/restore opened tasks" is unabled for some reason.
So the only way is to create it in task. 
So, how can I create 2×2 grid in task?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is your task contents. Checked in ConEmu build 120909.

```
>cmd -cur_console:n
cmd -cur_console:s1TVn
cmd -cur_console:s1THn
cmd -cur_console:s2THn
```

This is an example. Splitting in ConEmu may be as complex as you want, any configurations with any proportions are possible. Read project [wiki](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html) for more information about `-new_console` and `-cur_console` switches.

**To run all that without creating new Task**

There is `/cmdlist` `ConEmu.exe`'s switch.

Usage example for shortcut contents (on desktop, for example):

```
ConEmu -cmdlist cmd -cur_console:fn ||| cmd -cur_console:s1TVn ||| cmd -cur_console:s1THn ||| cmd -cur_console:s2THn
```

Need to run that from another cmd file? Here is `consoles.cmd` example:

```
start ConEmu -cmdlist cmd -cur_console:fn ^|^|^| cmd -cur_console:s1TVn ^|^|^| cmd -cur_console:s1THn ^|^|^| cmd -cur_console:s2THn
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to execute this command? I have tried and [this](http://cl.ly/MauX) is what I get. I have the latest build.

Comment: The key word is "Task". Why you trying to run this from already started shell? Setup Tasks.

Comment: @Maximus I had the impression that this was a shell command. Thanks.

Comment: @arin You may use this from shell too, but that need -new_console:... instead of -cur_console

Comment: @Maximus: How exactly is the window size configured in that task example? For example, I want to set up something like [what you posted on Twitter](http://t.co/55KYTMoS), where it's not a square grid. Is there some documentation you could refer me to?

Comment: @Isxek, link to project wiki was added to the answer

Comment: @Maximus: Thanks much! I'll see if I can get console Vim to work here.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following implementation. I use it for web development projects. Consoles for task runners (ex: gulp), git, javascript compilers (ex: typescript), etc. The goal was to open 4 console windows and change directory to the directory where I executed the *.cmd. I did not want to have multiple copies of the batch script incase I had to change it. I did not want the shell to be batch and I wanted the shell to be bash. I'm on windows, so, cygwin is needed for bash shell.

I created an arbitrarily named .cmd file. I called mine `4 consoles.cmd`. Cygwin is installed (the 64bit version in my case). Also the Cygwin `chere` package is installed and required.

`4 consoles.cmd` content:

```
@echo off

for %%i in ("%~dp0..\..") DO (set dirVar=%%~ni)
for %%i in ("%~dp0.") DO (set dir2Var=%%~ni)

set finalValue=%dirVar% %dir2Var%

start C:\"Program Files"\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe -cmdlist ^
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -c "/bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe" -cur_console:fna:t:"%finalValue%":C:"C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico" ^|^|^| ^
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -c "/bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe" -cur_console:s1TVna:t:"%finalValue%":C:"C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico" ^|^|^| ^
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -c "/bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe" -cur_console:s1THna:t:"%finalValue%":C:"C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico" ^|^|^| ^
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -c "/bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe" -cur_console:s2THna:t:"%finalValue%":C:"C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico"
```

I put `4 consoles.cmd` in a [File hosting service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_hosting_service) for backup purposes incase my hard drive crashes. Also for some convenience when sharing between development machines.

The batch script will change directory for all 4 console windows to the directory where the .cmd exists. So I created **Hard** [Symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)s in the directory where I want all 4 console windows to change directory into. The symbolic links point back to the canonical `4 consoles.cmd`.

Run a symbolic link and the 4 console shells working directories will be the location which the symbolic link is on the file system

My gulp task runner code for anyone that is interested

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-batch": "^1.0.5",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.1.6",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "author": "Author",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

`bower.json`

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.4",
    "jquery": "~2.1.3",
    "angular": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.3.0",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "~1.4.0",
    "angularjs-toaster": "~0.4.12",
    "angular-scroll": "~0.7.0",
    "moment": "~2.10.2",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.7.1"
  }
}
```

`gulpfile.js`

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var batch = require('gulp-batch');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var del = require('del');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('images', 'vendorCss', 'applicationCss', 'fontIcons', 'vendorJavascript', 'applicationJavascript');
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    del(['./dist/*'], cb);
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src([
            './content/img/**/*'
    ])
        .pipe(imagemin({
            optimizationLevel: 3,
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
            use: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/img'));
});

gulp.task('fontIcons', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        './bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**.*',
        './bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**.*'
    ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'));

});

gulp.task('vendorCss', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        './bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        './bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
        './bower_components/angularjs-toaster/toaster.css',
        './bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css',
        './bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.css'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('vendor.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('vendorJavascript', function () {
    return gulp.src([
            './bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            './bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            './bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            './bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            './bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
            './bower_components/angular-scroll/angular-scroll.js',
            './bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js',
            './bower_components/angularjs-toaster/toaster.js',
            './bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
            './bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js',
            './bower_components/underscore/underscore.js',
            './bower_components/moment/moment.js'
    ])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/script'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('vendor.min.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/script'));
});

gulp.task('applicationCss', function () {
    return gulp.src([
            './content/css/site.css',
            './content/css/animation.css'
    ])
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat('app.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('applicationJavascript', function () {
    return gulp.src([
            './angular/**/*.js'
    ])
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/script'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/script'));

});

gulp.task('watchApplicationJavascript', ['applicationJavascript'], function () {
    watch('./angular/**/*.js', batch(function (events, done) {
        gulp.start('applicationJavascript', done);
    }));
});

gulp.task('watchApplicationCss', ['applicationCss'], function () {
    watch(['./content/css/site.css', './content/css/animation.css'], batch(function (events, done) {
        gulp.start('applicationCss', done);
    }));
});
```