# Group windows so that they minimize and restore together?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Suppose I arrange four windows on two monitors, two on each, so that all 4 are visible. Then I go to other windows, or view the desktop. Normally, if I switch to one of the original four windows from the desktop, I would only see that window.

Is there a way to bring back all the 4 windows? Is there a software that can do that - like group windows so that they all restore together?

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/481443/application-to-group-windows-together) comes quite close to it. I'm not sure if Con-Emu will work across multiple monitors.

I know virtual desktops can solve some of this problem, but if i get distracted to other window inside my virtual desktop, it's the same problem again.

Comment: Just to be sure, you *have* tried Con-Emu, right? I don't see a reason that Con-Emu wouldn't work because of two monitors.

Comment: I haven't tried Con-Emu. It groups windows into one window, so I assumed it would be difficult to get it across two monitors. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or the `Show Desktop` button in the bottom right corner to view the desktop, just press it again and the windows will be restored.