# Hide/Show windows console?

Tags: windows, console

I have ~20 consoles that I don't want to see in my taskbar (which is already pretty full). At the moment I just build my app as window apps instead of console so I see nothing except the process in the process list (via task manager).

I like to see the console output once in a while. Is there an app I may use? Maybe something like linux screen would be nice.

Comment: Its not quite clear what you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ConEmu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) - Windows Console Emulator. I'm the author of it.

I suggest two ways to open bunch of tabs

1. Use of "Task file". It is a plain text file, each line - one new tab. Sample batch file

   ```
   echo "Z:\path\app.exe" %VAR%>%TEMP%\bunch.txt
   echo "Z:\path\app.exe" %VAR%>>%TEMP%\bunch.txt
   echo "Z:\path\app.exe" %VAR%>>%TEMP%\bunch.txt
   echo "Z:\path\app.exe" %VAR%>>%TEMP%\bunch.txt
   start "" "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe" /cmd @%TEMP%\bunch.txt
   ```
2. Another way use `/single` switch

   ```
   start "" "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe" /single /cmd "Z:\path\app.exe" %VAR%
   start "" "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe" /single /cmd "Z:\path\app.exe" %VAR%
   start "" "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe" /single /cmd "Z:\path\app.exe" %VAR%
   start "" "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe" /single /cmd "Z:\path\app.exe" %VAR%
   ```

PS. You can also open several consoles on one tab - [SplitScreen](https://superuser.com/a/473846/139371). And you may start several tabs with several splits.

Comment: I could have sworn i left a comment saying something similar to what i said to mark. I switch the build from windows to console and when i ran my startIt.bat from ConEmu it launched many console windows rather then have it in ConEmu using tabs. How do i get it in tabs?

Comment: How do you create run consoles exactly? Thought you need to run each console like "conemu /single /cmd <your command>".

Comment: Something like this http://pastebin.com/GXThg24U I don't care how i run it, i just want to set a variable and have many launch. I have 4 bat's like this which i double click to launch. With ConEmu i simply CD'd there and ran the file.bat from within. The start command launched it outside of ConEmu which I had a feeling of. I'm pretty sure everything suffers from that.

Comment: If i changed my bat file to do `conemu /single /cmd "Z:\path\app.exe" %VAR%` instead of `start` would that get what i want? all the instances in one ConEmu instance? -edit- I tried it. I dont think conemu is in my path but i ran that command within conemu and it didnt create a new tab

Comment: Thought, you need to add conemu dir to %PATH% or "App Path" (and "start conemu ...") or specify full path to exe.

Comment: Answer updated. Examples added.

Comment: Excellent app, I was thinking maybe theres no way to have it start with windows maxed but nope, i looked at the documentation and its right there /Max :D. I have 12+ tabs open and its running fine

Answer (score 2):

[Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) lets you run consoles (cmd.exe, PowerShell, whatever you configure) in tabs.

Comment: Nice, before I try it I want to know can i open a bunch of consoles using a bat file? bc i open about 3 bat of 6scripts (hence the almost 20)

Comment: Try ConEmu - it can.

Comment: @acidzombie24 - not sure, sorry. It doesn't seem like it. I tend to use start /min when I want to open command prompts minimized, and then have Windows Explorer just group running programs together so I only get the one window. It can make it harder to sort through them when there are many, though.