# How to make ConEmu attach on start

Tags: windows, batch-file, conemu

I have an existing .bat file which uses the `start` command to launch multiple tasks, e.g.:

```
start cmd.exe /k "echo task 1"
start cmd.exe /k "echo task 2"
start cmd.exe /k "echo task 3"
```

What happens is that ConEmu attaches only to the `cmd.exe` executing the `.bat` file, other `cmd.exe` instances start off as stand-alone windows:

[image: conemu start sample scenario]

I want the standalone `start`ed windows to be attached to ConEmu. I'm aware that I can achieve it by modifying the [batch script](https://superuser.com/questions/473807/%D0%A1onemu-how-do-i-make-several-console-windows-in-one-tab-from-task-file), but I don't want to do that because the script is shared with other people that don't necessarily use ConEmu.

Answer (score 4):

Considering this is proper behavior request. So build 141117 forces `start cmd` into new ConEmu tab.

Comment: Is there anyway to modify this new behavior? Problem: I run tcc scripts. Sometimes in the tcc script, I use cmd to launch an app with a clean environment. So now I get a new conemu tab AND the tab won't always go away because it complains the session lasted less that 10 sec. I launch cmd with the /min flag so I basically never saw the console before this change.

Comment: I agree with you in the sense that there should be a way to disable the 10sec time limit. I'm sure @Maximus can help here...

Comment: @Maximus it doesn't work in version 141126 and 141130 anymore

Comment: It is working on my side.

Comment: Simple test: `Win+R` -> `ConEmu -basic -cmd cmd` -> `start cmd`.