# How to get xterm-like split windows in Debian (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, bash, split-window

I'd like to achieve [this effect](https://superuser.com/q/55459/308586) in Linux. Essentially I'd like to have vim open on the left and have a command line on the right to perhaps tail an error log.

Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop, but CentOS on most of the boxes I'm sshing into, though I doubt any of that matters.

[How to get vertical split of terminal in Mac to execute different actions?](https://superuser.com/q/55459/308586)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `screen` or `tmux` programs on the CentOS servers to do this.

For example - for screen -
After you login, you run `screen` (you may have to install it)

Then hit `CTRL a` and then `CTRL |` <-- that's a pipe
This will split the screen into 2
Then hit `CTRL a` and then `CTRL tab` to switch to the new section
Then hit `CTRL a` and then `CTRL c` to create a new session in the new section.

The end result should be sessions side by side

Reference -
http://www.pixelbeat.org/lkdb/screen.html  (screen hotkeys)

---

Alternatively, on your Ubuntu desktop, you could get a terminal program that can do screen splits.
`Terminator` is one such terminal program, and you can split a screen by simply hitting `CTRL+Shift+e`